# Problems installing Daccord on macOS

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install a bioinformatics tool, called [Daccord](https://github.com/gt1/daccord) on my Mac.

Unfortunately my computer savvy is very limited and my troubleshooting is pretty much trial and error.

The README says:

> daccord needs libmaus2 https://github.com/gt1/libmaus2. libmaus2 needs to be built with support for the GMP library. When libmaus2 is installed in ${LIBMAUSPREFIX} then daccord can be compiled and installed in ${HOME}/daccord using
>
> ```
> autoreconf -i -f
> ./configure --with-libmaus2=${LIBMAUSPREFIX} \
>     --prefix=${HOME}/daccord
> make install
> ```

I did install `libmaus2` (at least I hope I did), I also installed GMP, but I have no idea whether `libmaus2` was "built with support for the GMP library".

My guess is that I have to replace `${LIBMAUSPREFIX}` with the right path? 
Maybe `${HOME}` too.

I tried `/usr/local/bin` because the libmaus-README said:

> By default, make install installs the package's commands under
>   /usr/local/bin, include files under /usr/local/include, etc.

I also tried the path of the `libmaus` release file.

So far the result is always:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libmaus2 >= 2.0.352) were not met:
No package 'libmaus2' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libmaus2_CFLAGS
and libmaus2_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Now, I additionally tried to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH using

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

/usr/local/lib contains libmaus2 and a lot of other files starting with libmaus2 so I would guess that's the right path. But

```
./configure --with-libmaus2=/usr/local/lib --prefix=${HOME}/daccord
```

or

```
./configure --with-libmaus2=${LIBMAUSPREFIX} --prefix=${HOME}/daccord
```

Still results in the error mentioned above.

Would be great if someone could give me a few pointers as to how to proceed.

Comment: Could you indicate the path where your libmaus2 is located and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

Comment: libmaus seems to be in /usr/local/lib. I just now changed the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /usr/local/lib. echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH now results in /usr/local/lib. ./configure --with-libmaus2=${LIBMAUSPREFIX} --prefix=${HOME}/daccord or ./configure --with-libmaus2=/usr/local/lib --prefix=${HOME}/daccord both still result in "No package 'libmaus2' found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that [libmaus2](https://github.com/gt1/libmaus2) was not correctly
installed, so you might need to really install it after all.

I'm not a user of libmaus2, but I did notice that it says that
you need to provide the libmaus2 base directory when calling configure for a dependent.

Meaning that if you configured libmaus2 with :

```
./configure --prefix=${HOME}/libmaus2
```

then you might use for building the dependent package :

```
./configure --with-libmaus2=${HOME}/libmaus2
```

I also have no idea whether libmaus2 is built by default with support for the
GMP library, but this might be a config parameter that you can check.

EDIT: 
Daccord is finally running after some help from the author. Here is how:

First, gmp had to be given the libmaus2 path:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Then libmaus2 had to be informed about that too:

```
./configure --with-gmp=/usr/local --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Then daccord could be installed with:

```
./configure --with-libmaus2=/usr/local --prefix=${HOME}/daccord
make install
```

And, all that has to be done with the newest release version of both [libmaus2](https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/libmaus2) and [daccord](https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/daccord), which are not hosted on github, but on gitlab.

Comment: As I said, I'm not a user of libmaus2. If this answer doesn't help you advance, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: Ah, well, first of all, thank you for your answer. I contacted the author and made some progress, but it doesn't run yet. I think you deserve the bounty for at least trying to help me out. I will probably edit your answer once I know the actual solution, if that's ok with you.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster: Which bounty ?

Comment: Did you not get it? I guess I had to accept the answer? I thought if there is only one answer it'll go to that one. I guess I'll bounty some more.

Comment: Ok, further bounties don't work because apparently bounties need to double every time and I'm 37 rep short of that right now. So sorry, seems like I wasted your time and my rep.

Comment: No matter, you aren't the first to make this error and won't be the last. Don't worry.